# What could be happening to my tomato plants?

Tags: tomatoes

I have a bunch of Roma tomato plants. Initially they were growing really well. I water them quite a bit, and every few weeks I add some organic "food" to them (I think it's just dried compost).

But in the past couple weeks they seem like their growth has tapered off and almost seem wilty.

Some of the fruit has rotted at the bottom oddly enough. It is growing tomatoes, some even large (for Roma tomatoes).

Any thoughts from the picture?

[image]

Comment: When you say rotted, do you mean blossom end rot?

Answer (score 7):

First, you should always know what you're using to fertilize your plants and why you're doing it. Anything sold as plant food/fertilizer is required to have a guaranteed analysis (3 numbers x-y-z) at least in the US. What exactly are you putting around your plants and how much? Looks like a lot.

Some of the leaves in the picture are curling up. This is an indication that you may be watering too much. Over-watering is a common problem with tomatoes. Wilting leaves get limp and fall down not up.

The rotting bottom of the fruit is called blossom end rot. It could be from inconsistent watering, too much fertilizer, insufficient calcium in the soil, unsuitable pH, high levels of ammoniacal nitrogen.

This page on [blossom end rot](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/hot_topics/2009/08blossom_end_rot.html) from Clemson's Cooperative Extension Office has a lot of useful information.

Water the plants only when they need it but water them deeply. The top of the soil should be dry. If you stick your finger about 1-2" in the soil and it's still feels moist then you don't need to water. Or you can wait until the plant seems like it's starting to wilt a little. The plant quickly recovers from a bit of wilting. Too much water is usually harder to recover from and too much water can have a negative result on the taste of the fruit, making it less sweet or diluting the flavor.

I suggest you get a soil test to check your pH and nutrient levels in your soil, if not for this year, for next year.